# Need to redirect to true root folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am running a website on MAMP, and the root is http://localhost/sandbox

When I have links that link to, for example - /calendar

it directs them to localhost/calendar, I want it to redirect to localhost/sandbox/calendar

What would I have to do in htaccess to get it to redirect everything to localhost/sandbox/ as the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually change the application or site that generates the links, and have that add the `/sandbox` to the URL.

If that's not possible, putting this into the web root directory (the one above `/sandbox`) should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sandbox  # If URL does not start with /sandbox... 
RewriteRule (.*) /sandbox/$1            # Add /sandbox/ in front of it
```

(if it's easier to achieve with `Alias`, Apache Gurus, feel free to add your solution, but I couldn't get Alias to work for this scenario.)

However, this solution will make any other directory besides `/sandbox` inaccessible. You may want to re-think your Virtual hosts structure!